# How to use passport.js's TwitterStrategy sessionless?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I tried to implement TwitterStrategy like it's done with Facebook in: 
[Token based, sessionless auth using express and passport](http://blog.jeroenpelgrims.be/token-based-sessionless-auth-using-express-and-passport/)

But express still wants me to use session middleware:

```
{"message":"OAuthStrategy requires session support. Did you forget app.use(express.session(...))?"
```

Can someone provide a detailed example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Passport twitter middleware issue reported earlier on [gihub](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/43)

```
Any OAuth 1.0 strategy requires sessions. OAuth 2 requires it if state is enabled (which is highly recommended). 
A temporary secret is stored in the session to prevent cross site scripting attacks.
```